# Multiple Integration

Tags: integration

How to do this multiple integration?

[image]

Need some guidance to start..

Comment: Do a change of variables to express this in a more apt curvilinear (oblique) coordinate system. Consider $u=3x+y,v=x+2y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the shaded area by calculating the area of each shaded region indicated below:

[image: drawing of areas accounted for by the various integrals]

The shaded area in your picture, is the sum of the areas of the yellow and orange regions above minus the sum of the areas of the green and blue regions.

First we compute the unidentified intersection points by solving the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
2y+x &= 3 \\
y+3x &= 6 \\
\end{align*}
for the first intersection point, and 
\begin{align*}
2y+x &= 2 \\
y+3x &= 3 \\
\end{align*}
for the second.

Now we can write the area of your shaded region as an equation involving integrals: $$\int_0^{1.2} 3-\tfrac{1}{2}x\ dx+\int_{1.2}^2 6-3x\ dx-\int_{0}^{0.8} 1-\tfrac{1}{2}x\ dx-\int_{0.8}^1 3-3x\ dx.$$

Comment: should the last integration part be $\int_{3/5}^2 1-x/2\ dx$

Comment: Fixed; thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try a change of variables: $u=2y+x$, $v=y+3x$.

Comment: by changing the variables, how does it help? can explain a bit more?

Comment: You will get a rectangle in the new variables.

Comment: can show how to do it? can't really visualize it..

Comment: what if u dun change variables? how to do it?

Comment: @lakesh these curvilinear coordinates simplify the region of integration: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer that hides explicit integration. (This is, however, essentially the same as other answers.)

The first thing you need is the coordinates of the lower left corner, which is $(0.8, 0.6)$.

**First Method (change of coordinates)**:

The area of the parallelogram is $|\det(u, v)|$, where $u$ and $v$ are vectors of two adjacent sides. In this case, $u = (-0.8, 2.4)$ and $v = (1.2, -0.6)$. Therefore, the area is $2.4$.

$|\det(u, v)|$ is the Jacobian determinant that is needed when transforming coordinates.

**Second Method (splitting into axis-aligned pieces):**

I will split the region into three $y$-axis-aligned pieces. ($x$-axis can also be used.)

This requires the coordinates of the upper left corner too, but by symmetry, it's easy to see that the corner is at $(1.2, 2.4)$.

The first piece is a triangle from $x = 0$ to $x = 0.8$. The second piece is a parallelogram from $x = 0.8$ to $x = 1.2$. The third piece is a triangle from $x = 1.2$ to $x = 2$.

The area of each triangle is $\frac 12 \times 0.8 \times 2 = 0.8$.

The area of the middle parallelogram is $0.4 \times 2 = 0.8$.

The sum of the three pieces is $2.4$.

**Inclusion Exclusion (same as Rebecca's answer):**

Call the shaded piece and the three pieces below it the "big region".
This is the piece on the left picture in Rebecca's answer.

Compute the area of this big region.
This can be done in many ways.
One way is to split the big region into $y$-axis-aligned pieces, like Rebecca did.
The area of the big region is $(trapezoid) + (triangle) = \frac 12 \times (3 + 2.4) \times 1.2 + \frac 12 \times 2.4 \times 0.8
= 3.24 + 0.96 = 4.2$.

The triangle whose corners are $(0, 0)$, $(2, 0)$, $(0, 3)$ has area $\frac 12 \times 2 \times 3 = 3$.

The difference in area of this triangle and the big region is $1.2$. This is half of the desired area.